# Unable to upload application to Amazon S3

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using Eclipse, latest version, latest Java AWS SDK I can suddenly no longer deploy to elasticbeanstalk (neither "Run on Server" nor AWS/Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk).

I can export a war file and upload via beanstalk web console w/o problems.
It used to work for months and I didn't change anything, credentials are ok.
The error message I get is:

> Unable to upload application to Amazon S3: AWS authentication requires
>   a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code:
>   403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: xxx)

Bump? Searched everywhere...
Any help truly welcome!

Comment: Show us your java code with amazon sdk

Comment: what does the code have to do with deployment via Eclipse?

Comment: oh, sorry, for misunderstanding, I thought that issue with runtime deployment via java code

Comment: I also have this problem on a macbook pro, but not a windows machine.  It does appear the macbook pro has newer versions of the eclipse AWS tools.  I will try @DanH answer and let you know if that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, may be of help to someone else.
The culprit was a script which wouldn't upload with a newer AWS SDK version and Eclipse (worked well within the web console). I could modify and export war file then upload via console. Now I had to remove all aws preferences (Windows: user dir .aws), delete all servers and in Eclipse Run as/Run on Server/Manually choose/choose from AWS list/and then in Next, on the bottom, "import an exsisting environment". Then just leave the dialog and a freshly generated server can then be selected. Thanks everybody for helping!

Comment: good to hear you got it to work.  I had also thought about going the .war and console method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently upgraded your eclipse SDK version?

I had a similar issue however was using the .NET Visual Studio SDK, try re-adding your account credentials within the eclipse plugin and check that you can successfully browse S3.

Steps can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup_creds.html#adding-your-aws-access-keys-to-the-tke

Comment: I tried just re-applying my credentials, and re-started eclipse - but I still have the problem.  Did you delete the credentials first?

Comment: Yes remove all existing profiles within the plugin,  and then re add them.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar error reported on my eclipse AWS installation on my MacBook Pro.

I had

> AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core (Required)    2.3.1.v201508061154
>   AWS Elastic Beanstalk      1.0.0.v201508062254

installed.

To fix this, I completely uninstalled all the AWS plugins from eclipse and then added them from the http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse  site,
and then removed the AWS elastic beanstalk app and environment from the beanstalk server.

In this process, I had to enter my AWS credentials, and setup the AWS server, app and environment.  I am now able to deploy my AWS web app from eclipse.

Comment: Tried that, now I get "An internal error occurred during: "Updating AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment: xxxx". Unable to create client: null".

Comment: Also tried to remove and re-install all AWS plugins from Eclipse but to no avail. The strange bit is that in the AWS Explorer beanstalk shows all servers and all else appears to be fine, while the S3 node shows "unable to connect" which is strange because it works just fine in the web console and also S3 Browser app. Running out of options what to re-install or update to...ran thru several (and of course the latest) AWS SDK(s).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. My solution:

1. Remove all aws preferences (Windows: user dir .aws)
2. Uninstall the AWS Plugins (Help->About->Installation Details). On the installed Software tab, highlight all AWS plugins and select uninstall.
3. I then Reinstalled required plugins from: http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse and all was well again.

(There were restarting of eclipse between uninstall and reinstall too)

No need to remove the environments and create new ones.