# AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, jodatime

I'm trying to deploy my project to amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk (with eclipse) but I'm getting the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 649FE9210F6B7758), S3 Extended Request ID: rPaO3PhaiVUP3Nwt6ORehaZUICUJ0nh+Ij8od3Aiq9RoTZtwaZipVyDRI+Hr6qa67A1vwgjpbJo=
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1077)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:725)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3699)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1434)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1294)
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.elasticbeanstalk.ElasticBeanstalkPublishingUtils.publishApplicationToElasticBeanstalk(ElasticBeanstalkPublishingUtils.java:123)
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.elasticbeanstalk.jobs.UpdateEnvironmentJob.run(UpdateEnvironmentJob.java:189)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)


eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.8.0_66
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
```

I tried the following:

1. Added joda-time 1.8.1 to WebContent\WEB-INF\lib and also added the jar to my dynamic web project.
2. verified the version with

   `new DateTime().getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()`

but I'm still getting this error.
I tried to search for additional solutions but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have **Java 1.8u60**?

As specified [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/444), **JodaTime** has problems with formatting time zones starting with **Java 1.8u60**.

Upgrading to **JodaTime** version **2.8.1** or later solves the issue.

They have created pull request for this: [JodaOrg/joda-time#291](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/pull/291).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes I have java 1.8.0_66 and JodaTime 2.8.1 abd still not working.

Comment: Is java 1.8.0_66 is the same as 1.8u60?

Comment: The full version string for this update release is 1.8.0_60-b27 (where "b" means "build"), except for OS X, where the version string is 1.8.0_60-b28. The version number is 8u60. Try with 1.8.0_60.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with java version jdk1.8.0_60 greater downgrade it to jdk1.8.0_45 will solve the problem

Comment: But I am using Java SE 7..still facing the same issue .

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to fix this problem with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559607/unable-to-upload-application-to-amazon-s3) question
In addition to re-installing the aws toolkit I also re-installed eclipse.